# What is the image of the strip $0\le\Re(z)\le2$ under $z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z}?$

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is the image of the strip $0\le\Re(z)\le2$ under $z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z}?$

Please help me. I'm clueless.

Comment: do you know that this function must map a straight line to either a straight line or a circle?

Comment: @IttayWeiss: yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $ z \to 1/z$ is a Möbius (or fractional linear) transformation, so the image of a straight line or circle is a straight line or circle.  What's the circle through $0$ and $1/2$ that is symmetric wrt the real axis?